Where did Edmund Mortimer and Catrin Glyndwr marry in 1402?
Where did Edmund Mortimer and Catrin Glyndwr marry in 1402?
Could it have been Harlech? Sycharth? Somewhere else?
I presume it was wherever Owen Glyndwr himself was in November 1402.
I can't find the answer in the Wikipedia articles linked or on the Mortimer History Society website I have also read Glanmor Williams Owain Glyndwr (Cardiff,1993), Ian Skidmore, Owain Glyndwr (Swansea,1978) and A G Bradley, Owen Glyndwr (London, 1901) without finding the answer.

Actually Bradley does provide an answer: The monk of Evesham tells us that the marriage was celebrated with the greatest solemnity about the end of November, though where the ceremony took place we do not know.
